# PrimeNG multiselect onItemClick not working after update to 7

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have an MultiSelectComponent which extends primeng MultiSelect

After update from 6.1.6 to 7.0.4

```
<ul class="not-important"
   <li *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" class="not-important"
   (click)="onItemClick($event, option)"
```

Property 'onItemClick' does not exist on type 'MultiSelect'. What is the replacement? Can't find something in documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) it looks like they have not updated it.

After looking at the source code, you should now be using `onOptionClick()`

You can see the changes here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/993f856be9bb864057753e3a9c033f0d60ad7334#diff-3bc7dd3fc5e401bc174d2d8475540a34

So you would need to change your code to

```
<ul class="not-important"
   <li *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" class="not-important"
   (click)="onOptionClick($event, option)"
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7100) with the PrimeNG team to correct the documentation

Comment: not working: 
TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'EventEmitter<any>' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: there is onClick on MultiSelectItem but not on MultiSelect

Comment: If you look at the github commit, you can see that they renamed `onItemClick` to onOptionClick` on the MultiSelect Component.

Comment: tried this with $event but...
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined

Comment: Your code in question does not show any `disabled` properties. So I'm not sure how to help with that.

Comment: appreciated for your help. Have found a solution

Answer (score 1):

i have found a solution (no clue what happened on primeng)

```
public onMyClick(event: any, option: any): void {
    event.option = option;
    super.onOptionClick(event);
}
```

Call `onMyClick` on click event on `<li>` item.